# jQuery DOM cross-browser updating problems

Tags: jquery, dom, cross-browser

I am running a jQuery animation driven splash / web page with (soon to be) hash and hijax driven links and pages. When proceeding through the splash to a specific page, every modern browser is capable of hijaxing links and applying the jQuery rollovers, etc.

However, when going directly to a hashed link from an outside page or refreshing the page the DOM either does not load fast enough or at all (surprisingly it works best in IE, eventually in FF, and rarely in chrome / safari).

Also, the splash page does not render properly in either chrome or safari due to what I assume are more jQuery problems.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, I am sure that Im missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I've noticed:

- Please upgrade to jQuery 1.4.1.
- You shouldn't need to use livequery just to animate your banner image.
- Use `hover` instead of focus and blur on the links. Focus doesn't work the same across all browsers and it is meant to work on input elements... I'll dig out my example link and show you.
- I can't figure out why you are changing your hash links but not your content. Check out this really nice [ajax tutorial](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/011_jQuerySite/sample/index.html) (if that is what you are trying to do).

---

I found the demo I made... [posted here](http://pastebin.me/973509bd873d9ef90fa19c961e77fb27). Note that `.focus()` only works on input elements and links. It also isn't supported properly in Chrome and Safari. Also `focus()` and `focusin()` (v1.4) have the same results.

Comment: No I dont have any problem loading AJAX content I just havent written that part yet. I am setting up all the links to hash properly before I start loading content, so if javascript is on they will fade / load into the next page, and if not it will go through the basic links in the PHP.


My problem was that on certain browsers, when loading an hashed bookmark or link, the jQuery does not load into the DOM fast enough or at all (hashing the links and adding the rollovers for users with javascript enabled).

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2 seems to have solved the DOM loading problems, now I just need to get the splash to be properly positioned in the middle for chrome / safari!